# Log only real fatal errors from PHP-FPM in Docker container

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, fpm

I'm using NGINX with PHP-FPM in seperated Docker containers. I want to get errors only to stderr, so that I can collect them on a centralized log-server. Problem is: I'm using WP and seems to have some not well written plugins. They work but cause warnings like this:

> 2017/06/17 01:16:08 [error] 7#7: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP
>   message: PHP Warning:  Parameter 1 to wp_default_scripts() expected to
>   be a reference, value given in /www/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 601

Example script for testing, which should give me a fatal error in the stderr:

```
<?php
not_existing_func();
```

PHP-FPM was configured to log errors to stderr like this:

```
[global]
log_level = error
error_log = /proc/self/fd/2
```

I'm wondering that this gave me nothing in the script above. Just after I switched the `log_level` to at least `notice`, I got the exception on the console of the docker container:

> [17-Jun-2017 01:45:35] WARNING: [pool www] child 8 said into stderr:
>   "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to
>   undefined function not_existing_func() in /www/x.php:2"

Why the hell is this a **notice**? For me we've clearly a fatal error here like the message indicates, cause the script can't continue (and we get a 500 error in the browser, of course). It can't be true that I have to set `log_level` to `notice` so that I don't miss fatal errors which are delcared as warnings. And simultaneously, my logs get filled with *trash* warnings from wordpress themes, plugins and so on, that I haven't developed and I don't want to fix for update reasons...

I tried a bit and found out that `log_errors` in `php.ini` is essential for PHP-FPM to get any information. But the log level from `error_reporting` seems wired too. For testing purpose, I used the following configuration:

```
display_errors = Off
log_errors = On
error_log = /proc/self/fd/2
;error_reporting = E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_ERROR|E_CORE_ERROR
error_reporting = 0
```

Result: I got notices, but NO info about my fatal error...

Answer (score 5):

First of all, I learned that I was wrong: **Wordpress is the root cause for this issue**, not PHP directly. It's a known fact that WP manipulates the `error_reporting` when debugging is enabled, so I tried to define `WP_DEBUG` as `false` in my config; BUT even having this set, the [documentation says](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php)

> [...]
> Except for 'error_reporting', WordPress will set this to 4983 if WP_DEBUG is defined as false.
> [...]

So my settings into `php.ini` were correct and sufficient. I don't even need the *php-fpm* settings, when errors are redirected to stdout in the `php.ini` file.

### How to prevent WordPress from manipulating the error reporting?

This is not so easy, too. Although the WordPress documentation says, that the `wp-config.php` is a good place to set global wide settings like the error reporting, [they got overwritten later to `4983`](https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/). I don't know where; maybe it's not even the Core of Wordpress, but rather some poor developed plugin or theme.

We can handle this by adding `error_reporting` to the disabled functions:

```
disable_functions = error_reporting
```

Now it's not possible to overwrite our `error_reporting`. I think this is the best solution to make sure that we don't get any other error reporting by external influence from plugins or themes. Also in the future, since PHP allows such chaos, we need to reckon with such things.

Basically, we could criticize that this prevent us from getting more logs by setting `WP_DEBUG` to true, that's right, but as we're on a production system, it seems wrong for me to do troubleshooting in such a way there. We shouldn't do this on an application base, especially without `display_errors`! Instead, the workflow to find problems should be to look at the error logs.

Fatal errors should always be logged and checked on a regular basis. If that is not enough, `error_reporting` could be set on a higher level to get information about possible problems like warnings.